# how to update docker image without losing its content?

Tags: image, docker, containers

I've been developing a website where I store pictures on the server. I used Docker to run my app. During the testing, I found that when I kill the docker and build an image again I lose all saved pictures. As I understood, when I upload a picture to the server it saves them inside of the container, and when I kill it destroys the created files inside of it. Every time when I add new features I kill the docker and build it again and lose all pictures. What I am doing wrong?

I have committed changes in my container to its image. Can I build the image on top of the existing image? can I merge them?

Comment: Can you redesign your application to not store content in its local filesystem?  That's the best path: it avoids this problem, and it's basically required if you're looking at running it in a clustered environment like Kubernetes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using [Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

These can be used to persist data between containers

Alternatively you can [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) storage to a container - but i believe volumes might be more appropriate for you